# Why `--array.length` delete the last element of the array?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, chrome console:

```
var test = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> undefined
var lastIdx = --test.length
> undefined
lastIdx
> 4
test
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
var lastIdx = --(test.length)
> undefined
lastIdx
> 3
test
> [0, 1, 2]
```

As you already saw, I just want to get the last index of the array through the `--array.length`, but unfortunately the last element of the array get removed unexpectedly, really cannot understand how come this can/should happen, can someone explain?

Comment: `--` does not mean just "one less than this number". It also decreases whatever you apply it to.

Comment: as always, JS and his weird stuffs...

Comment: use var lastIdx = test.length - 1

Comment: @felipsmartins - nothing weird about expected behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--x` decrements `x` and returns the new value. (`x--` decrements `x` and returns the old value.) So `--test.length` reduces the length by 1.

If you just want to get last index without modifying the length, that would be `test.length - 1`.

Comment: In other words, it's like saying `array.length = array.length - 1`